# Gravity property for textview is not centering the text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a textview in a LinearLayout, the width is set to match parent and the gravity is set to center. Well, this is not centering the text in the textview. It makes the left side of the text to start at the center of the view. I have been reading some answers on stack overflow and it seems that everything is ok.

Here the simple xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Try to set gravity center_vertical for your LinearLayout. This will set your TextView at the center of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to align to center? The TextView object itself or it's text?

I think there are two gravity attributes.

android:layout_gravity which will align the TextView object in the LinearLayout in your case, could be left, right center etc.

android:gravity will align your texts/string in the TextView it could be again left, right, center etc.

I hope that helped you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `API` to `Android 2.2`. I also had the same problem and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This can sound a bit weird, but I brought the code to another computer and it worked as it is. Really weird.

Thanks!.